# About reading txt file and converting to adjacent list of graph

Tags: c, file

Well, I'm dealing with Graph problems but real problem that makes me angry is I'm in trouble with NOT a graph but about file input. It's language is C, so I can't use any libraries of C++.

txt file is like this.

10

0 1

1 0 2 3

2 1 4

3 1 4 5

4 2 3

5 3 6 7

6 5 7

7 5 6 8 9

8 7

9 7

first number, number of vertex and each line,
datas linked in each vertex[n].

I'm doing various methods like fgets and strtok with 'SPACE'
but I'm not sure this is right, too.

How can I get number-by-number with line-by-line?

Ex.
Vertex[0]=[0,1]
Vertex[1]=[1,0,2,3] ...
I want to read data like this

Thank you.

Comment: you didn't post any code. Personally, I would just do it right, then worry about replacing library stuff one at a time (if you have working code, and automated tests, then you'll know exactly when you broke something trying to play with pointers)

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I did with strtok and atoi. Thank you for reply.